# If Galaxy-class ships had been developed by 2360, why couldn't they scout for the voyager crew?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

Voyager was lost in 2371, now I realize that for a long time the Alpha Quadrant probably had no idea where Voyager was or if it was even still operating, but at some point during the series they made contact through a communication relay network.  At that point they must have had a pretty fair idea as to where Voyager was, why were they unable to send a Galaxy-class ship to retrieve them?

Comment: Galaxy-class ships are older (and slower) than Voyager..  The name of that class ship doesn't mean it can easily traverse the galaxy.

Comment: You answered the question that I should have asked.  It was the class designation that confused me.

Comment: And considering how finicky the warp cores on those ships were (how many times did it nearly blow up in TNG?), the show would have been over in the first season.

Comment: It’s a ruddy long way to the Delta Quadrant. See http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1536/can-anyone-explain-the-star-trek-astrography-i-e-quadrants

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [communications network](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Hirogen_communications_network) you're referring to covered an extemely large area of the galaxy. Although Star Fleet knew where Voyager was it would have been a very large undertaking to send a rescue mission to redevous with Voyager, with odds of success likely nearly as poor as Voyager's were of returning on their own. Aside from that, had Voyager found their own way back (as they did) then Star Fleet would have still had another ship left in deep space, potentially needing its own rescue (which if they had sent a Galaxy class ship would have meant nearly 10 times the number of people on Voyager in danger).

Answer (score 34):

Starfleet had no idea what happened to *Voyager* in the Badlands. They searched for several months with no trace, and assumed the ship was lost.

It wasn't until "[Message in a Bottle](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Message_in_a_Bottle_%28episode%29)" that they finally learned of *Voyager*'s existence in the Delta quadrant. Once they did, they immediately initiated the [Pathfinder Project](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Pathfinder_Project) to figure out a way to bring them back home.

In "[Pathfinder](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Pathfinder_%28episode%29)", we learn that Starfleet has spent several months and considerable amount of resources trying to figure out a way to bring them back home quickly. This project was initially a failure, namely because any ship sent out to meet *Voyager* would have to make the return trip home: potentially risking the lives of a whole other crew while taking years to complete.

So Starfleet did the next best thing, with the help of *Voyager*, by establishing regular contact. *Voyager* gets several lucky breaks via technology way beyond Federation knowledge and winds up on the verge of the beta quadrant by after only 7 years.

In the end, it took a future Captain Janeway and the disruption of the Borg transwarp network to finally bring *Voyager* back into Federation space. We learn in "[Endgame](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Endgame)" had that not happened, it would've taken another 16 years. So even at the end of their journey, it would've taken Starfleet 8 years to meet *Voyager* even halfway, and another 8 years to get back. Endangering the lives of another crew for that long would not have been considered [an acceptable risk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eVIt0DYKssI#t=1m57s).

Answer (score 6):

Sending a ship to meet Voyager would not have made the return trip any faster. That's why I never understood the part when somebody said that 2 ships had been sent to meet Voyager and they would meet "in a few years". That's bad writing at best. There's no way sending a ship (except something like the Dauntless, faster than a speeding bullet) would have helped.

Comment: It might have made the trip safer & therefore more likely to succeed.  Having a fleet of ships, including ships with different capabilities (one that could produce replacement parts etc) would have made more sense.

Comment: @AidanO: Having a fleet of ships traveling through space that is controlled by unknown entities is just begging to be met by a larger fleet of ships of unknown origins, capabilities, and intents. Voyager had to constantly bargain with other space-faring entities to travel through claimed regions of space. Good luck making those bargains when you have a fleet.

Comment: @Ellesedil, i'm not so sure, wouldn't unknown ships be less likely to attack if there was more than one?  While I agree having a fleet could have presented it's own problems. At the end of the day it would all depend on how the writers decided to write it I guess!

Comment: @AidanO: I would expect any civilization interested in defending their boarders would interpret a fleet of ships crossing said boarders (an invasive act) as an invasion. Even when Voyager was solo, they were often met with initial hostility and had mixed success trying to be diplomatic. Adding 10 more ships to the equation will just compound the problem because now it's a show of force.