# Location of the Yorktown Starbase

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond

In the film "Star Trek: Beyond" we see the Yorktown Starbase. We are only told that it is buildt in interstellar space, to not prefer some race, and also that the base is near the Necro Cloud Nebula.

Are there sources that state where the base is located? I don't know which maps you can find online are canon, especially in the Kelvin timeline, so I leave that to you.

Comment: It's in the JJ-verse, which is a region of space full of temporal anomalies :-D  Seriously though, excellent question, however I don't recall it being addressed in the movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canonically, the location of the Starbase, the nearby Necro Cloud and the planet Altamid haven't been confirmed. We know that they're near the ...

> "edge of Federation Space"

... as of 2263, but there's no indication where that *actually is*. **The Necro Cloud, nor any of the other planets or features mentioned in the film correspond to anything on any of the [existing maps of the Star Trek universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54222/is-there-a-galactic-map-showing-the-homeworlds-of-the-various-humanoid-species).**

---

It might interest you to know that [Simon Pegg](https://twitter.com/simonpegg/status/757894165984313344) placed the planet Altamid in the **Andromeda Galaxy**, 2.5 million light-years from Earth. This is a journey that would take the USS Voyager, traveling at top speed, more than 3000 years to complete.

[image]

Comment: Ok, that confirms what I have found... that there is nothing. Andromeda Galaxy is highly unlikely.. even and especially for the Kelvin Timeline, which confirms my feelings that the creators of the new films may actually know less about Star Trek then even I do =)